# How to judge a point with Lat and Lon about whether it is in land or sea?

Tags: javascript

I just want to judge a point with Lon/Lat about whether it is in land or sea in my front-end program. I want to konw how to do it with JavaScript. Any WebAPI can be used freely?

Comment: Like https://simoneprimarosa.com/is-sea/ ?

Comment: Yes,but how can i call the API in my own front-end program?It seems like the one you mentioned is judged directly in its js program

Comment: you need to tell us more information on your setup...

Comment: The web application you mentioned above is written by you? I just want to determine the range of interpolation because i only need ocean range rendering using canvas. I write my application using pure Javascript and Openlayers .Could you tell me how the application realize the function that i want?Thanks so much!